# Cannot Access Camera from Android 10 Web View

Tags: android, webview, android-camera, android-10.0

On upgrade to Android 10 the onShowFileChooser code I have been using inside my Hybrid Android Web View App since Android 5 or 6 stopped providing access to the camera. The user could still access stored photos, but the camera option was no longer offered to the user.

The code I had been using is show below

```
      //For Android 5.0+
    public boolean onShowFileChooser (WebView webView, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePathCallback, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams)
        {
        if(mUMA != null)
            {
            mUMA.onReceiveValue (null);
            }
        mUMA = filePathCallback;
        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity (MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null)
            {
            File photoFile = null;
            try
                {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
                }
            catch(IOException ex)
                {
                Log.e(TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
                }
            if (photoFile != null)
                {
                mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra (MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile (photoFile));
                }
            else
                {
                takePictureIntent = null;
                }
            }
        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory (Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType ("image/*");
        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null)
            {
            intentArray = new Intent[] {takePictureIntent};
            }
        else
            {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
            }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent (Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra (Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);
        startActivityForResult (chooserIntent, FileChooserActivityCode);
        return true;
        }
```

together with the following code to process the result

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent)
    {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

    if (requestCode == FileChooserActivityCode)
        {
        Uri[] results = null;
        //Check if response is positive
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
            {
            if (null == mUMA)
                {
                return;
                }
            if (intent == null || intent.getData() == null)
                {
                //Capture Photo if no image available
                if (mCM != null)
                    {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(mCM)};
                    }
                }
            else
                {
                String dataString = intent.getDataString();
                if(dataString != null)
                    {
                    results = new Uri[]{Uri.parse(dataString)};
                    }
                }
            }
        mUMA.onReceiveValue(results);
        mUMA = null;
        }
    }
```

I have found out how to access the camera from [this link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/issues/328) and changed the takePictureIntent code to the following :

```
    if(takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(MainActivity.this.getPackageManager()) != null) {

    File photoFile = null;
    Uri photoUri = null;

    if (isAndroidQ) {
        // Android Q compatibility
        photoUri = createImageUri();
        mCameraUri = photoUri;
        if (photoUri != null) {
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCM);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Image file creation failed", ex);
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            mCM = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
        } else {
            takePictureIntent = null;
        }
    }
}

private Uri createImageUri()
        {
        String status = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
        if (status.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
            {
            return MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            }
        else
            {
            return MainActivity.this.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, new ContentValues());
            }
        }
```

But now after taking the photo inside the onActivityResult code the variable mCM is null and nothing is passed to the web view.

Please can someone tell me what I have missed?

Answer (score 2):

If you are targeting Android 10 - this version introduces a new, more secure/private way for accessing storage named Scoped Storage. check out [THIS](https://medium.com/better-programming/all-you-need-to-know-about-scoped-storage-in-android-10-e621f40bc8b9) article for more info how to implement

for more complex solution you should show what happens in `createImageUri` and `createImageFile` methods

[HERE](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/media) we have nice doc how to handle old and new way

optionally you can disable new access way, but only for Android 10, starting 11 this support will be required. Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` for `<application>` tag in manifest

Comment: optionally you can disable new access way, but only for Android 10, starting 11 this support will be required. Add android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true" for <application> tag in manifest

Comment: well, to be precise it isn't... as long as app targets 10 and have `requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` everything will work on Android 11 and above. another problem is that Google Play forces apps to publish/update versions targeting only 2 versions below current (good move!)

Answer (score 1):

**For Android 10, SDK 30**

Add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` for `application` tag in manifest

*Starting from marshmallow, android requires user permissions to access camera and external storage. Without these permissions, the Webview app can’t initiate a camera upload, so you have to make the user to grant permissions, So here is how to fix camera upload in android Webview.*

**Add  this code below the OnCreate method.**

```
if(!hasPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS)){
          ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, PERMISSIONS, PERMISSION_ALL);
      }
```

**Then add this code in the activity**

```
int PERMISSION_ALL = 1;
   String[] PERMISSIONS = {
           
           android.Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
           android.Manifest.permission.CAMERA
   };

   public static boolean hasPermissions(Context context, String... permissions) {
       if (context != null && permissions != null) {
           for (String permission : permissions) {
               if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, permission) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                   return false;
               }
           }
       }
       return true;
   }}
```

*Remember that you will have to declare permissions in your android manifest too.*

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        tools:ignore="ScopedStorage" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Answer (score 0):

All in needed to add was

```
else if (mCameraUri != null)
                    {
                    results = new Uri[]{mCameraUri};
                    }
```

Comment: Could you post the solution please?